# Подсветка активной ссылки

Tags: php

Например в меню есть ссылки, для переходов по страницам. При кликаньи на ссылку загружается определенная страница, а сама ссылка получает класс "**активная**" с подсветкой например. Как это реализовать? Я заключил ссылки в массив, пхп выводит их в цикле и проверяет, если  href совпадает с гет-запросом, ссылка получает класс "активная". Но это мешанина кода и представления. Что-то мне подсказывает, что все делается не так... А как?

Comment: всё зависит от того как у вас устроено всё остальное...

Comment: @eicto, думаю не имеет значения. В общем виде бы. Вообще реализация. У меня есть стат.свойство Router::route, которое содержит href ссылки, например "main","login" и ссылки соответственно href="/main", href="/login", перебираю ссылки в цикле и вот - при совпадении - подсветка. Не нравится мне что-то это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Костыль #1:

```
<style type="text/css">
#<?=$menu_active_item?> {
  //стиль css для подсвеченного элемента
}
<style>
```

Костыль #2

```
function a($path,$html=''){
  $active='';
  if($path==$_GET['controller'].'/'.$_GET['action']){
    $active = 'active';
  }
  printf('<a class="menuitem %s" href="/%s">%s<a>',$active,$path,$html);
}
```

Без костылей - создать нормальную функцию во view, которая принимает массив или объект.
Еще лучше, если этот объект сам умеет себя нарисовать. Таки да, у вас будет проверка, но цикл на странице будет как во втором варианте:

```
foreach($menu_items as $item){
   draw_menu_item($item['path'],$item['html']);
}
```

С объектом:

```
foreach($menu_items as $item){
   $item->draw();
}
```